# Is this MVC in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, model-view-controller, console-application

I am new to stackoverflow, so hello!! This is my very first question.

My code is written in **python** and its a console application. Its a project from the book "Object Orientated Programming Design with Python 3" which I am trying to customise and change so that it is MVC so I can progress with my fundamentals. My program currently works perfectly in the console and presents a menu that when I type in a number corresponding to the menu it lets me perform a notebook task.

My question is a conceptual one about Model View Controller.

I have split my program into three different modules.

1. Notebook (which has my Notebook and Note classes)
2. Controller (which has my view logic and has my run method)
3. View (which just has my display menu function)
   (I have not included a model as I have no data/database hooked up)

So my question are!

1. Is this MVC?
2. If not how would I structure this to be MVC?
3. Would someone please help me understand by refactoring my code (making it mvc so I can understand how its properly implemented?
4. How would I integrate the **model** part of MVC (if I wanted to store my memo notes in a database)?

My different modules code listed below.

## NOTEBOOK MODULE CODE

```
import datetime

# store the next available id for all new notes
last_id = 0


class Note:
    """Represents a note in the notebook. Match against
    a string in searches and stores tags for each note.
    """

    def __init__(self, memo, tags=''):
        """Initialize a note with a memo and optional
        space - separated tags. Automatically set the note's
        creation date and a unique id."""
        self.memo = memo
        self.tags = tags
        self.creation_date = datetime.date.today()
        global last_id
        last_id += 1
        self.id = last_id

    def match(self, filter_notes):
        """
        :param filter_notes: Determine if this note matches the filter
        string.
        :return: Returns True if it matches, False otherwise.
        """
        return filter_notes in self.memo or filter_notes in self.tags


class Notebook:
    """ Represents a collection of notes that can be tagged,
    modified, and searched
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize a notebook with an empty list
        :return: NOTHING! Just initializes an empty list.
        """
        self.notes = []

    def new_note(self, memo, tags=''):
        """
        Create a new note and add it to the list.
        :param memo: input string memo notes
        :param tags: input tag for searching
        :return: Create a new note and adds it to the
        self.notes[] list.
        """
        self.notes.append(Note(memo, tags))

    def _find_note(self, note_id):
        """
        Locate the note with a given id. (_FIND_NOTE FUNCTION FOR
        INTERNAL USE ONLY)
        :param note_id: Passed into an if statement for matching
        :return: A matched note if found in the list of notes
        """
        for note in self.notes:
            if str(note_id) == str(note_id):
                return note
            return None

    def modify_memo(self, note_id, memo):
        """Finds the note with the given id and changes its
        memo to the new given value.
        """
        note = self._find_note(note_id)
        if note:
            note.memo = memo
            return True
        return False

    def modify_tag(self, note_id, tags):
        """Finds a note with the given id and changes its
        tag to the new given value."""
        tag = self._find_note(note_id)
        if tag:
            tag.tags = tags
            return True
        return False

    def search(self, filter_notes):
        """
        Find all notes that match the given filter string.
        :param filter_notes: Filter string passed
        :return: A list of of notes that match the filter string
        """
        return [note for note in self.notes if
                note.match(filter_notes)]
```

## CONTROLLER MODULE CODE

```
from notebook import Notebook, Note
from view import View


class Controller:
    """Display a menu and respond to choices when run."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.notebook = Notebook()
        self.view = View()
        self.choices = {
            "1": self.show_notes,
            "2": self.search_notes,
            "3": self.add_notes,
            "4": self.modify_notes,
            "5": self.quit
        }

    def run(self):
        """Display the menu and respond to choices."""
        while True:
            self.view.display_menu()
            choices = input("Enter an option: ")
            action = self.choices.get(choices)
            if action:
                action()
            else:
                print("{0} is not a valid choice".format(choices))

    def show_notes(self, notes=None):
        if not notes:
            notes = self.notebook.notes
            for note in notes:
                print("{0}: {1}\n{2}".format(
                    note.id, note.tags, note.memo))

    def search_notes(self):
        filter_notes = input("Search for: ")
        notes = self.notebook.search(filter_notes)
        self.show_notes(notes)

    def add_notes(self):
        memo = input('Enter a memo: ')
        self.notebook.new_note(memo)
        print("Your note has been added.")

    def modify_notes(self):
        id = input("Enter a note id: ")
        memo = input("Enter a memo: ")
        tags = input("Enter tags: ")
        if memo:
            self.notebook.modify_memo(id, memo)
        if tags:
            self.notebook.modify_tag(id, tags)

    def quit(self):
        print("Thanks for using your notebook today!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Controller().run()
```

## VIEW MODULE CODE

```
class View:

    def display_menu(self):
        print(""" Notebook Menu

1. Show all Notes
2. Search all Notes
3. Add Notes
4. Modify Notes
5. Quit
""")
```

Any help, advice and feedback would be greatly appreciated (if I need to clarify further or have not provided enough detail or even to much detail let me know, and I will address it). Also I am saying thanks in advance for anytime spent helping me out! :)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of MVC is slightly different to how your code is organised.

I'd tend to call the `Notebook` class a model as it *stores* data (no database is needed for it to be a model). And it only has basic logic specific to locally handling notes.

I would have the view class having a reference to the controller class, not the other way around. The view class is the point of contact for user interaction, both input *and* output, and would hold the `input` and other "gui" functions, along with minimal logic for handling the response. The view would have a reference to and call the controller class to do real logic, which in turn would modify the model. In your example the logic is fairly simple and it's OK to combine the view and controller (which is essentially what you've done).

Typically a view will also "listen" for changes to the model and update itself as the model is changed, but in the case of a single threaded console program like this that doesn't really apply and it's fine to just look up model data (via the view having a reference to the model) when responding to a user request.

One way to start is with a code pattern like this:

```
notebook = Notebook()
controller = Controller(notebook)
view = View(notebook, controller)
```

which forces your classes to only have downstream references.

Then again, MVC is somewhat subjective and if this works for you then I'd say it's fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) will code something simpler and post it hopefully its closer to the mark.